# Maintain Android activity Stack with notifications

Tags: android, stack, manifest, whatsapp

I'm developing a simple chat application with more than 8 activities. But my main problem is with two activities of my application. Think on whatsapp, it has a Main Activity (contact list) and chat activity, and always, whatsapp application maintains stack state starting application from application list or long pressing HOME. Also if application starts from notification, never appear duplicated activities in the stack. I would like to copy this behaviour in my application but I have tried all the possibilities and always is a case where an activity isn't destroyed, duplicate activities on the stack, all those problems trying to maintain stack state when going back to app.

Anyone knows how to implement it?

- Activity A-> Contact List
- Activity B-> Chat Activity

What are the parameters in the manifest for each activity?

And for the intent notification? I want notification launch activity B and pressing back button to go to activity A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but here are two things that may help:

- [`android:noHistory`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist): set this attribute to true in the manifest for activities that are supposed to leave no trace in the activity stack. So if you're going ActivityA --> ActivityB (noHistory=true) --> ActivityC, and the user presses the back button, then you go back to ActivityA, because ActivityB is already unloaded.
- [`Activity.finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29): the activity that this is called on quits itself. The usual callbacks (`onStop()`, `onDestroy()`) are called. If you want to prevent duplicate activities, it may help to call this in the `onPause()` of the activity you don't want duplicated.

If those aren't enough, then there are a lot more details in the 'back stack' documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Problem is that notification intent launches Activity A as new task with Extra parameters, because when activity A is loaded gets intent Parameters and launches ActivityB, so when i'm finished with Activity B, pressing Back button it goes to Activity A, but if in this moment i press home, and after that, return to my app long pressin home, it launches Activity A again with intent parameters that launches Activity B, so i'm in activity B again. Problem appears when i have launched my app from launcher and i press home, after that if i enter pressing a notification problems appears.